# Does contemporary usage of "neither...nor..." for more than two options originate in the US?

Tags: phrase-usage, neither-nor

I use ***either...or / neither...nor*** to introduce *two* alternatives - '*this*' or '*that*'.  So I was surprised to read the following in (British) *The Spectator* magazine -

> If the same claim were made on TV, on radio or in print, it would have been rejected because it’s *neither legal, decent, honest nor truthful*.

The use of *neither* to herald a list of *more* than two things sounds wrong to my British ears.

The OED defines *either* as both

> each of two

*and*

> each of more than two

However the OED labels the second of these usages both 'obsolete' and 'nonstandard'.

Well, obviously the usage is not obsolete!  Not only did I read it in a British magazine today but also it is used in the official motto of the *United States Postal Service*: "Neither snow nor rain nor heat nor gloom of night stays these couriers from the swift completion of their appointed rounds" (an adaptation in the early 20th century of words by Herodotus, about 2500 years ago).

British and American English is full of interesting differences. And new Americanisms are regularly being added to British English.  Is neither/either (for more than two items) an old-time usage that the UK dropped but the USA retained (and is now exporting back to the UK!)?

Comment: Yes, it's not limited to two. This is the official motto of the United States Postal Service, for instance: "Neither snow nor rain nor heat nor gloom of night stays these couriers from the swift completion of their appointed rounds."

Comment: Would you prefer "because it’s illegal, indecent, dishonest and untruthful"? (Four different ways that negation is done.) I suppose they did it that way because those four qualities are the hallmark of acceptable advertising in the UK, as required by the Advertising Standards Authority

Comment: The usage with either ("either A, B, or C") is common in both British and American English, no?

Comment: (I'm not aware of any dialectical difference here, though certain usage manuals frown on using either/neither for more than two things.)

Comment: I think the *truly* nonstandard sense applies when using "neither" without "nor." As in: "There are three people in line. Neither are being patient."

Comment: @alphabet Always *neither is*.

Comment: You skipped something in the *OED*? See **either**  **II.** Expressing alternatives. **3.** In correlative constructions with a conjunction, introducing the mention of alternatives. // Samples: *Heads either of Men, Beasts, or Birds, are very frequent in Armoury... // He..was forbidden..to touch either map, ephemeris, book of astronomical observations, sextant, time-keeper, or any of my surveys or drawings // A narration of events, either past, present, or to come // I would not have thought of eating a meal without drinking either wine or cider or beer*

Comment: @TinfoilHat - I did see that part and in fact that was when it occurred to me that perhaps it was an old English usage that the UK has dropped but that the US held on to and is now exporting!  In the section you cite there are only three examples after 1900 and of these three only one uses 'either' to introduce three options - Hemingway!

Comment: @alphabet I agree with you and with tchrist. The correct usage would be "None [of them] is being patient."

Comment: "[I]t’s neither legal, decent, honest nor truthful" is readily understood, distinguishes "truthful" from the other items mentioned, and emphasizes it. Saying "it's not legal, decent, honest or truthful" lacks that emphasis, so the quoted phrase can be viewed as a rhetorical construction.

Comment: @Wastrel - interesting, though it doesn't work as a rhetorical emphasis for me.

Comment: @Dan Well, to expand on that... I suggest reading it aloud, with a pause before the "nor" and you will see what I mean, I think. The "neither" makes a listener expect a "nor." I suppose the difference is not much, because you could do much the same thing with "or truthful." And maybe I'm just wrong :-)

Answer (score 9):

I think it's not so much an Americanism as prescriptive grammar.

First, Americanism is not mentioned in the relevant sections of either [*A Comprehensive Grammar of the English Language* (Quirk, et al.)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Comprehensive_Grammar_of_the_English_Language) or [*The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* (Rodney Huddleston and Geoffrey K. Pullum)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Cambridge_Grammar_of_the_English_Language).

***A Comprehensive Grammar of the English Language***

> **13.39 Restrictions·on correlatives** 
> According to a didactic tradition, the use of correlative coordinators is unacceptable when there are three or more conjoins:
> ?We are *both* willing, able, *and* ready to carry out the survey. [1]
> ?*Either* the Minister, *or* the Under-secretary, *or* the Permanent Secretary will attend the meeting. [2] 
> ?Tompkins has *neither* the personality, the energy, *nor* the experience to win this election. [3]
> ...
> ...
> Although commonly stigmatized, multiple correlatives such as [1-3] can add clarity to constructions whose complexity might otherwise cause confusion. For this reason, such constructions are sometimes used even in careful written English, *eg* in the rubric of an examination paper:
> Candidates are required to answer *EITHER* Question 1 *OR* Question 2 *OR* Questions 3 and 4.

***The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language***

> ***Neither* as marker of coordination** 
> As a marker of coordination, *neither* is usually paired correlatively with *nor*. It can occur (like *either*) in multiple as well as the more usual binary coordination, and (like *both*) it cannot occur initially in a coordination of main clauses:
>  
> [48] i *She found it* [***neither** surprising **nor** alarming*]. [binary] 
> ii *He was* [***neither** kind, handsome, **nor** rich*]. [multiple] 
> iii ****Neither** did he oversleep **nor** was his bus late*. [main clause coordination]

Being descriptive grammars, both CGELs (written by British linguists) endorse the multiple coordination.

[***Garner's Modern English Usage***, Fifth Edition (a prescriptive usage manual written by an American legal scholar and lexicographer)](https://global.oup.com/academic/product/garners-modern-english-usage-9780197599020?cc=kr&lang=en&), on the other hand, does not endorse the multiple coordination, although it acknowledges there are attested examples of the usage among well-educated people:

> **B. Number of Elements.** These correlative conjunctions best frame only two elements, not more. Though it’s possible to find both modern and historical examples of *neither . . . nor* with more than two elements, these are unfastidious constructions. When three or more are involved, it’s better not to say **They considered neither x, y, nor z*. Instead, say *They didn’t consider x, y, or z*. Or it’s permissible to use a second *nor* emphatically in framing three elements: *They considered neither x, nor y, nor z*. Cf. either (b).
> Language-Change Index
> *neither . . . nor* with more than two elements: Stage 3

FYI, Stage 3 means this:

> Stage 3: The form becomes commonplace even among many well-educated people, but it’s still avoided in careful usage. Examples include **adopted mother* for *adoptive mother*; **gladiolas* for *gladioli* or *gladioluses* (or simply *glads*); *idyllic* for *ideal*; **miniscule* for the correct spelling *minuscule*; the supposed contraction **’til* for the good old word *till* (as in *We’ll be here till noon*); *peruse* used to mean “scan hastily” rather than “read carefully”; and using a nominative pronoun in compound objects such as **between you and I* rather than *between you and me*.

Comment: It's a strange one. Or perhaps it's me. But I find _Huddleston and Pullum_'s  'neither kind, handsome, nor rich' perfectly fine to my ears, their 'either Kim, Pat, or Alex' less so, and 'The disease was neither cholera, typhoid, nor typhus' somewhat grating.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Quirk, et al. did touch on the issue in the portion I've omitted: "It is perhaps understandable, then, that the use of correlatives with more than two conjoins is judged if anything a more obvious stylistic 'fault' in [6], where the conjoins are noun phrases, than in [1], where they are not:
?* _Both_ her mother, her father, _and_ her brother are still alive. [6]" Although they only talked about _both...and_, the same can be said about _neither...nor_ and _either...or_.

Comment: I'd include this in the answer.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Interesting! With "neither," to me it sounds better if (as in the USPS motto) you repeat the conjunction: "neither cholera, nor typhoid, nor typhus" sounds better than "neither cholera, typhoid, nor typhus." That motto is from 1914, so it isn't *that* new of a usage.

Comment: @alphabet - I agree.  The usage sounds less strange with repeated *'nor'*s.  Perhaps because repeating the '*nor' creates (an illusion of) one-to-one comparisons with the first in the list?

Comment: @alphabet That's been suggested by Garner.

Comment: @Dan I suspect it's partly because you typically put more stress on neither/nor: "*neither* cholera *nor* typhoid *nor* typhus"; if you leave out the first "nor" it breaks up the rhythm, giving you the awkward-sounding "*neither* cholera, typhoid, *nor* typhus." I don't think "either/or" is always stressed in the same way, so they may not have the same issue.

Answer (score 7):

Despite being considered non-standard by the OED according to OP’s statement, it appears that the usage of ***either…or*** and ***neither…nor*** can extend to more than two items with the Bard himself and Dr. Samuel Johnson ([*The Oxford Dictionary of National Biography* calls him "arguably the most distinguished man of letters in English history"](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samuel_Johnson)) using the terms with more than two items. So this usage likely started on the British side of the pond as OP mentioned.

According to [Grammarphobia](https://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2017/08/either-neither.html)

> **Either” and “neither” usually refer to only two things, but not always.**
>
> When “either” showed up in Old English as ǽghwæðer (also contracted as ǽgðer), it meant “each of two.” And when “neither” showed up in Old English as nauðer (næþer in early Middle English), it meant “none of two.”
>
> Yes, there’s clearly an etymological two-ness about the terms. And as we’ve said, that’s the way “either” and “neither” are generally used.
>
> However, **writers haven’t been confined by etymology when the terms are used to introduce a series**, as in these examples from Shakespeare:
>
> “They say there is divinity in odd numbers, either in nativity, chance, or death” (from *The Merry Wives of Windsor*, circa 1597).
>
> “You know neither me, yourselves nor any thing” (from *Coriolanus*, c. 1605-08).
>
> If Shakespeare’s not good enough for you, how about Samuel Johnson? His biographer, James Boswell, quotes the great lexicographer as saying “neither tea, nor coffee, nor lemonade, nor anything whatever.”
>
> ***The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* notes that the duality of “either” and “neither” is weakened when they’re used as conjunctions to introduce a series.**
>
> The authors, Rodney Huddleston and Geoffrey K. Pullum, say the two terms can be used “in multiple as well as the more common binary coordination.”
>
> Huddleston and Pullum give these examples: “either Kim, Pat, or Alex” and “neither kind, handsome, nor rich.”
>
> Standard dictionaries generally accept the use of “either” or “neither” to introduce a series of more than two items.
>
> *Merriam-Webster Unabridged*, for example, says “either” can be used “before two or more coordinate words, phrases, or clauses joined usually by or.” It defines “neither” as “not one of two or more.”
>
> However, dictionaries say “either” and “neither” refer to only two alternatives when used as an adjective (“I’ll take either flavor, vanilla or chocolate”) or a pronoun (“Neither [of them] for me”).
>
> We gave examples above of Shakespeare’s use of “either” and “neither” with more than two items. We’ll end with an example from *Hamlet* (c. 1600), in which he overdoes the usage to emphasize the pedantry of Polonius:
>
> “The best actors in the world, either for tragedy, comedy, history, pastoral, pastoral-comical, historical-pastoral, tragical-historical, tragical-comical-historical-pastoral, scene individable, or poem unlimited.”

Comment: I think the adjective/pronoun uses is the important distinction. In those cases we have "any" and "none" when there are more than 2.

Comment: "Despite being considered non-standard" by whom?

Comment: OP wrote “ However the OED labels the second of these usages both 'obsolete' and 'nonstandard'.” I’ve edited my answer to clarify this point.

Comment: Oh, thanks. I don't have access to OED, but I wonder if it's really what OED says.